# Django CharField not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
from django.db import models

class Pet(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = [('M','Male'), ('F', 'Female')]
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    submitter = CharField(max_length=100)
    species = CharField(max_length=30)
    breed = CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    sex = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES, max_length=1, blank=True)
    submission_date = models.DateTimeField()
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    vaccinations = models.ManyToManyField('Vaccine', blank=True)


class Vaccine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

With this code I am getting command line error when running "python manage.py makemigrations".
name "CharField" is not defined.

How to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `CharField` class to module imports,
ie,

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CharField
```

But, this isn't a right way to import modules in your projects. So change your `models.py` as follows,

```
from django.db import models

class Pet(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = [('M','Male'), ('F', 'Female')]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    submitter = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    sex = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES, max_length=1, blank=True)
    submission_date = models.DateTimeField()
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    vaccinations = models.ManyToManyField('Vaccine', blank=True)


class Vaccine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: It worked.... Thank you Jerin Peter George.....   I was stuck since yesterday.... May God bless you....

Answer (score 1):

You used `CharField` directly instead of `models.CharField` in some of your declarations.

This should do:

```
from django.db import models

class Pet(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = [('M','Male'), ('F', 'Female')]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    submitter = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    sex = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES, max_length=1, blank=True)
    submission_date = models.DateTimeField()
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    vaccinations = models.ManyToManyField('Vaccine', blank=True)


class Vaccine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this :

```
from django.db import models

class Pet(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = [('M','Male'), ('F', 'Female')]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    submitter = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    sex = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES, max_length=1, blank=True)
    submission_date = models.DateTimeField()
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    vaccinations = models.ManyToManyField('Vaccine', blank=True)


class Vaccine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```